# Excel 2010 Hyperlinking Cells

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in an excel document (workbook).  They have the same number of cells in the same arrangement. The first sheet contains summary information and the second sheet (in the corresponding cell) contains the more detailed information.

I want to hyperlink the sheets so that, a person can click the summary cell to be brought to the detailed cell.

I know I can use the following formula to create a hyperlinks:

HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])

And (at least in Excel 2010) the "link_location" entry must be in the format "#BOOK!Cell" where the quotes must be included.

However, when you click on a cell to make a selection, the formula processes it simply as BOOK!CELL.  Its possible to drag and have the other cells auto populate with the BOOK!CELL format.  But then I just have a bunch of broken cells.  Any advice on how to automatically populate my first sheet with the correct format?

Comment: Could you show a sample of what exactly you are trying to do? Your input and your expected output in the hyperlink cells?

Comment: Please post what formula you've tried.  That'll help narrow down the crux of the issue.

Comment: The output should be that every cell (or every cell in a given row to start) should be a hyperlink to the corresponding cell in the detailed sheet with the "friendly text" of the original value of that cell in the summary sheet.  I'll end up doing this through a third sheet, i.e. remaking the summary sheet where by each cell's link value = detailed sheet cell and helper value = summary sheet cell.  My problem is the syntax issue described above, not this portion of the execution.

Comment: It sounds like you would need `Indirect()`, but am not positive. Can you please post a sample of the data and what you expect it to look like with your formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the subaddress to link to a place in the workbook.  I would run this example below which would update all links to reflect the other sheet location.  Change the name of the sheets to your two sheet names.

```
Sub FixMyLinks()
On Error Resume Next
Dim c As Range
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim wsDetails As Worksheet

Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDetails = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each c In wsSummary.UsedRange.Cells
        wsSummary.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:=wsDetails.Name & "!" & Replace(c.Address, "$", ""), TextToDisplay:=c.Value
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I should first link them all with the "wrong" formatting as described in my post and then run this in the VBA terminal?

Comment: You don't need to link them as that is what the code will do.  From my understanding, sheet 1 cell A1 should link to sheet 2 A1.    Make a copy of your workbook.   Then run the VBA code on it so you can see how it will produce the results if you do not fully understand it.   I believe it is what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It says "invalid procedure call" and when I click debug it highlights the row below For Each. I changed the values of Sheet1 to be the correct name of the sheets.

Comment: Do you have blank cells in the used range?  There is no error handling for a blank cell.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so helpless on this. I didn't see a place (in the formula) to select a range. Is the range in question just the entire excel sheet?

Comment: The used range is all the cells in the worksheet that have data.  I have added On Error Resume Next so that it will pass over blank cells.