# How to give hyperlink for particular name in excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

If I give hyperlink for cell A1 in Sheet1, that link automatically should go to A4 in Sheet2. I mean if I click on “Apple” it should go to where the “Apple” Cell in Sheet2 even (Where ever it is in Sheet2) if it is shuffled in Sheet2. Here in Sheet2 the cell is not important the “Apple” is important, like Vlookup function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpmXe.jpg)

Comment: This was recently asked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548106/excel-2010-hyperlinking-cells/34548461#34548461

Comment: The linked question does not address the problem, because the requirement here is for the hyperlink to perform more complex logic than simply navigating to a fixed destination. Instead it needs to perform a lookup, hence using worksheet_followhyperlink method is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. You don't want cells to be linked to a fixed destination, but rather have the destination determined at runtime, when the user clicks the link, based on the contents of the cell.

The only way to implement this is to have the target of the hyperlink pointing to the cell itself. Then in the workbook_followhyperlink method of the sheet, it should interpret the cell value, and direct the user to the right destination (or do any other action - I often use this to make a network path 'clickable' and open it in explorer).

Comment: Yes I don't want cells to be linked to a fixed destination.... I want the text containing in cell only... means particular name or text in worksheet... Is it possible to put formula without Visual Basic.. please tell me..

Comment: You need to use vb, no way around it. Do some research on the follow hyperlink method.